# Reshaping a 1D bytes object into a 3D numpy array

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm using FFmpeg to decode a video, and am piping the RGB24 raw data into python.

So the format of the binary data is:

```
RGBRGBRGBRGB...
```

I need to convert this into a `(640, 360, 3)` numpy array, and was wondering if I could use `reshape` for this and, especially, how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `rgb` is a bytearray with `3 * 360 * 640` bytes, all you need is :

```
np.array(rgb).reshape(640, 360, 3)
```

As an example:

```
>>> import random
>>> import numpy as np
>>> bytearray(random.getrandbits(8) for _ in range(3 * 4 * 4))
bytearray(b'{)jg\xba\xbe&\xd1\xb9\xdd\xf9@\xadL?GV\xca\x19\xfb\xbd\xad\xc2C\xa8,+\x8aEGpo\x04\x89=e\xc3\xef\x17H@\x90]\xd5^\x94~/')
>>> rgb = bytearray(random.getrandbits(8) for _ in range(3 * 4 * 4))
>>> np.array(rgb)
array([112,  68,   7,  41, 175, 109, 124, 111, 116,   6, 124, 168, 146,
        60, 125, 133,   1,  74, 251, 194,  79,  14,  72, 236, 188,  56,
        52, 145, 125, 236,  86, 108, 235,   9, 215,  49, 190,  16,  90,
         9, 114,  43, 214,  65, 132, 128, 145, 214], dtype=uint8)
>>> np.array(rgb).reshape(4,4,3)
array([[[112,  68,   7],
        [ 41, 175, 109],
        [124, 111, 116],
        [  6, 124, 168]],

       [[146,  60, 125],
        [133,   1,  74],
        [251, 194,  79],
        [ 14,  72, 236]],

       [[188,  56,  52],
        [145, 125, 236],
        [ 86, 108, 235],
        [  9, 215,  49]],

       [[190,  16,  90],
        [  9, 114,  43],
        [214,  65, 132],
        [128, 145, 214]]], dtype=uint8)
```

You might want to look at existing [numpy and scipy methods for image processing](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing/). [`misc.imread`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html) could be interesting.

Comment: Oh yeah, that worked. I had to use `reshape(360, 640, 3)` because otherwise the image was rotated 90 degrees. I also had to make ffmpeg output in the `bgr24` format or the hues were all wrong.

Comment: Downvoter: constructive criticism is welcome. Otherwise, please stop downvoting random answers from me.